# Counting occurrence of words in table is slow

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, performance, like, query-performance

Consider these simplified tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.words
(
    id bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    word varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    hits int NULL
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.items
(
    id bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    body varchar(256) NOT NULL,
)
```

The `words` table holds about 9000 records, each holding a single word ('phone','sofa','house','dog', ...)
The `items` table holds around 12000 records, each with a body text of no more then 256 characters.

Now, I need to update the `words` table, counting how many records there are in the `items` table that hold (at least once) the text in the *word* field. I need to account for partial words, so all these 4 records should be counted for the word *dog*:

```
'This is my dog'  
'I really like the movie dogma'  
'my cousin has sheepdogs'  
'dog dog dog doggerdy dog dog'
```

That last example should count as just one record (contains the term 'dog' at least once).

I can use this query:

```
UPDATE dbo.words
SET hits = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.items WHERE body like '%' + word + '%')
```

But, this is extremely slow, this will take over 10 minutes to complete on the not to heavy server I have for it.

AFAIK indexes won't help, I'm doing LIKE searches.
I also think full-text won't help me, since I'm looking for words starting, ending or containing my search term. I could be wrong here.

Any advise on how to speed this up?

Answer (score 9):

The best way I have found to speed up leading wildcard `LIKE` searches is to use n-grams. I describe the technique and provide a sample implementation in [Trigram Wildcard String Search in SQL Server](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-wildcard-search).

> The basic idea of a trigram search is quite simple:
>
> 1. Persist three-character substrings (trigrams) of the target data.
> 2. Split the search term(s) into trigrams.
> 3. Match search trigrams against the stored trigrams (equality search).
> 4. Intersect the qualified rows to find strings that match all trigrams.
> 5. Apply the original search filter to the much-reduced intersection.

It may be suitable for your needs, but be aware:

> Trigram search is no panacea. The extra storage requirements, implementation complexity, and impact on update performance all weigh heavily against it.

### Test

I ran a quick test using the *Complete Works of Shakespeare* to populate the `body` column of the `items` table with 15,838 rows. I loaded the `words` table with 7,669 unique words from the same text.

The trigram structures built in around 2 seconds and the following update statement completed in **5 seconds** on my mid-range laptop:

```
UPDATE dbo.words WITH (TABLOCK)
SET hits = 
(
    SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) 
    FROM dbo.Items_TrigramSearch
        ('%' + word +'%') AS ITS
);
```

A selection of the updated words table:

[image: sample]

The modified trigram scripts from my article are below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GenerateTrigrams (@string varchar(255))
RETURNS table
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN
    WITH
        N16 AS 
        (
            SELECT V.v 
            FROM 
            (
                VALUES 
                    (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
                    (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)
            ) AS V (v)),
        -- Numbers table (256)
        Nums AS 
        (
            SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.v)
            FROM N16 AS A 
            CROSS JOIN N16 AS B
        ),
        Trigrams AS
        (
            -- Every 3-character substring
            SELECT TOP (CASE WHEN LEN(@string) > 2 THEN LEN(@string) - 2 ELSE 0 END)
                trigram = SUBSTRING(@string, N.n, 3)
            FROM Nums AS N
            ORDER BY N.n
        )
    -- Remove duplicates and ensure all three characters are alphanumeric
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        T.trigram
    FROM Trigrams AS T
    WHERE
        -- Binary collation comparison so ranges work as expected
        T.trigram COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9a-z]%';
GO
-- Trigrams for items table
CREATE TABLE dbo.ItemsTrigrams
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    trigram char(3) NOT NULL
);
GO
-- Generate trigrams
INSERT dbo.ItemsTrigrams WITH (TABLOCKX)
    (id, trigram)
SELECT
    E.id,
    GT.trigram
FROM dbo.items AS E
CROSS APPLY dbo.GenerateTrigrams(E.body) AS GT;
GO
-- Trigram search index
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX
    [CUQ dbo.ItemsTrigrams (trigram, id)]
ON dbo.ItemsTrigrams (trigram, id)
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW);
GO
-- Selectivity of each trigram (performance optimization)
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.ItemsTrigramCounts
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT ET.trigram, cnt = COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM dbo.ItemsTrigrams AS ET
GROUP BY ET.trigram;
GO
-- Materialize the view
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX
    [CUQ dbo.ItemsTrigramCounts (trigram)]
ON dbo.ItemsTrigramCounts (trigram);
GO
-- Most selective trigrams for a search string
-- Always returns a row (NULLs if no trigrams found)
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Items_GetBestTrigrams (@string varchar(255))
RETURNS table
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
    SELECT
        -- Pivot
        trigram1 = MAX(CASE WHEN BT.rn = 1 THEN BT.trigram END),
        trigram2 = MAX(CASE WHEN BT.rn = 2 THEN BT.trigram END),
        trigram3 = MAX(CASE WHEN BT.rn = 3 THEN BT.trigram END)
    FROM 
    (
        -- Generate trigrams for the search string
        -- and choose the most selective three
        SELECT TOP (3)
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                ORDER BY ETC.cnt ASC),
            GT.trigram
        FROM dbo.GenerateTrigrams(@string) AS GT
        JOIN dbo.ItemsTrigramCounts AS ETC
            WITH (NOEXPAND)
            ON ETC.trigram = GT.trigram
        ORDER BY
            ETC.cnt ASC
    ) AS BT;
GO
-- Returns Example ids matching all provided (non-null) trigrams
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Items_GetTrigramMatchIDs
(
    @Trigram1 char(3),
    @Trigram2 char(3),
    @Trigram3 char(3)
)
RETURNS @IDs table (id integer PRIMARY KEY)
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
BEGIN
    IF  @Trigram1 IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF @Trigram2 IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            IF @Trigram3 IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                -- 3 trigrams available
                INSERT @IDs (id)
                SELECT ET1.id
                FROM dbo.ItemsTrigrams AS ET1 
                WHERE ET1.trigram = @Trigram1
                INTERSECT
                SELECT ET2.id
                FROM dbo.ItemsTrigrams AS ET2
                WHERE ET2.trigram = @Trigram2
                INTERSECT
                SELECT ET3.id
                FROM dbo.ItemsTrigrams AS ET3
                WHERE ET3.trigram = @Trigram3
                OPTION (MERGE JOIN);
            END;
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                -- 2 trigrams available
                INSERT @IDs (id)
                SELECT ET1.id
                FROM dbo.ItemsTrigrams AS ET1 
                WHERE ET1.trigram = @Trigram1
                INTERSECT
                SELECT ET2.id
                FROM dbo.ItemsTrigrams AS ET2
                WHERE ET2.trigram = @Trigram2
                OPTION (MERGE JOIN);
            END;
        END;
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- 1 trigram available
            INSERT @IDs (id)
            SELECT ET1.id
            FROM dbo.ItemsTrigrams AS ET1 
            WHERE ET1.trigram = @Trigram1;
        END;
    END;

    RETURN;
END;
GO
-- Search implementation
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Items_TrigramSearch
(
    @Search varchar(255)
)
RETURNS table
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN
    SELECT
        Result.body
    FROM dbo.Items_GetBestTrigrams(@Search) AS GBT
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        -- Trigram search
        SELECT
            E.id,
            E.body
        FROM dbo.Items_GetTrigramMatchIDs
            (GBT.trigram1, GBT.trigram2, GBT.trigram3) AS MID
        JOIN dbo.Items AS E
            ON E.id = MID.id
        WHERE
            -- At least one trigram found 
            GBT.trigram1 IS NOT NULL
            AND E.body LIKE @Search

        UNION ALL

        -- Non-trigram search
        SELECT
            E.id,
            E.body
        FROM dbo.Items AS E
        WHERE
            -- No trigram found 
            GBT.trigram1 IS NULL
            AND E.body LIKE @Search
    ) AS Result;
```

The only other change was to add a clustered index to the `items` table:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cuq ON dbo.items (id);
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you need it to be faster? You cancelled the query after 10 minutes but you don't really have a way to judge progress. What if the query was 90%+ done when you cancelled it? How fast do you truly need the query to be? How often will you run an update like this?

I'm asking these questions because I can get a similar `UPDATE` to finish on my machine in 144 seconds when running at `MAXDOP 1`. The query is also a pretty good fit for query parallelism. When I force the query to run at `MAXDOP 8` it finishes in 20 seconds on my machine.

Note that collation can matter quite a bit here. The numbers above are with the collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`. If I change the column collation to `Latin1_General_CI_AS` then the code is about eight times slower. In addition, perhaps my test data and hardware is significantly different than yours. I still suggest estimating the total run time of your query and then deciding if you need to try a more exotic solution. You can do this by creating a temp table with 1% of the rows in `dbo.words` and seeing how long the `UPDATE` takes for the smaller table. If you multiply the query execution time by 100 that should be a fairly good estimate for the real thing.

In the code below, I used `CHARINDEX` instead of `LIKE` because it's faster when just checking for an occurrence of a string in another string. If needed, the `UPDATE` query can be encouraged to run in parallel with an undocumented use hint [`ENABLE_PARALLEL_PLAN_PREFERENCE`](http://www.queryprocessor.com/how-to-get-a-parallel-plan/). Here's the query:

```
UPDATE #words
SET hits = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #items WHERE CHARINDEX(word, body) > 0)
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE #items
(
    body varchar(256) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #items WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT TOP (12000) text
FROM sys.messages
WHERE LEN(text) <= 256
AND CAST(text AS VARCHAR(256)) = CAST(text AS NVARCHAR(256))
ORDER BY LEN(text) DESC;

CREATE TABLE #words
(
    id bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    word varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    hits int NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

INSERT INTO #words (word, hits)
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (9000)  LEFT(word, 32), NULL
FROM (
    SELECT LEFT(body, CHARINDEX(' ', body)) word
    FROM #items

    UNION ALL

    SELECT LEFT(body, -1 + CHARINDEX(' ', body)) a
    FROM #items

    UNION ALL

    SELECT RIGHT(body, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(body)))
    FROM #items

    UNION ALL

    SELECT RIGHT(body, -1 + CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(body)))
    FROM #items
) q;
```

Comment: Hey Joe, 1) Did I say I canceled the query? This query runs every night and always takes just upwards of 10 minutes. I would ideally run it more often, we import external data in to the system several times per day, and running it then would be helpful. I'll test your suggestions on another machine. This one is still running outdated SQL Server 2012 Express. My firsts test did not show any difference when testing with the MAXDOP option and a 100 records data set.
Thank you for this suggestion! I will look in to it further!

Comment: @palloquin, please keep in mind that you have access to much more information than we do. All that we have to go on is what you put in the question. When people around here say something like "this will take over 10 minutes to complete" usually that means that they gave up after ten minutes. If a query did finish then it's possible to give an upper bound for the query execution time instead of just a lower bound. In your case, it would be helpful for us to say "The query usually takes under 15 minutes and needs to finish in X minutes". Happy to edit in response to that. Thanks!

Comment: @palloquin It would also be helpful to add the SQL Server version to the question. With Express edition you don't have access to parallel queries, so part of my answer is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of an SQL way, but if you're willing to think outside the box, there is a different approach that may be viable. Your dataset is fairly small. `256 * 12000 + 32*9000 = 3360000`. That's a little over 3MB; this data easily fits even inside the CPU cache of most modern CPUs. Thus you could write a little application in your programming language of choice that simply selects all the data, performs the calculation, and updates the data back. This should take but a few seconds.

If it's still too slow, check which kind of loop is faster - first over words then over items, or the other way round. If the overhead of your programming language is big enough that the data *doesn't quite* fit in the CPU cache, one of these will be faster than the other.

Comment: Fair enough. Perhaps stepping outside SQL might be the way to go, I could look at keeping it close to the DB by writing a CLR Stored Procedure for it. Need to dust off some skills for that. I'll go play with this and the trigrams options mentioned before. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT /* THE TEXT TO BE SEARCHED */ AS searchText,
       SUM((LEN(fieldNameOfDB)
          - LEN(REPLACE(fieldNameOfDB, 'THE TEXT TO BE SEARCHED', '')))
           /LEN('THE TEXT TO BE SEARCHED')) AS noOfOccurances
FROM TableName
```

Comment: fieldNameOfDB implies the column name from the given table